# How to slide a secondary view to reveal a main view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a program that loads a main view and when a user presses a button in the main view, the app loads a second view.

What I want to do after loading the second view is while a person slides their finger to the right the second view will also slide back to the right and reveal the main view.

Additional info:

I have been experimenting with the following code in my to create sliding effects, but it only works in the main view. Is there a possible way to create the same sliding effects in a secondary view controller that is not initialized when the app launches?

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

Comment: On swipe change the offset of the secondary view controller's view to a distance based on the swipe distance.  When it reaches some threshold, pop the view controller and its view off the UI stack.  Check out UISwipteGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to be able to access the slide out pane, on any screen and not just the first?

If so, then you have to setup a navigation controller, and push the new view controller onto the navigation controller. Then in the new view controller, you need to add and remove gesture recognizer accordingly.

example scratch code:

Navigation controller

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
MyViewController2 *VC = (MyViewController2 *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"screen2"];
[nav pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

then in your second view controller,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    //add gesture recognizer here, as you did in the first vc
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
    //remove gesture recognizer here
}
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use storyboards for this?

Comment: yes it is, just click on your first View Controller, Editor, Embed in, Navigation Controller. Now just cntrl-drag from first viewcontroller, to second view controller, a popup appears just select push. But also, the way you added the gesture recognizer line of code in your first vc, add it to your'e second vc also.